# Grafana Default Dashboard Install and Config

Tags: installation, prometheus, grafana, dashboard

I ve just installed Grafana v 7.3.3, prometheus 2.22.2, node_exporter 1.0.1

After install everything went fine and no problems occurred. And so, I import the default dashboar in order to test grafana which contains many panels such as grafana version which is running on server.

When I access my server on port 3000, I can see many variables and one of them is `grafana_build_info{branch=“HEAD”,edition=“oss”,goversion=“go1.15.1”,revision=“2489dc4d3a”,version=“7.3.3”} 1`

My issue is that all panels on default dashboard appears as NA, grafana version is one example, but as I wrote above, that variable is available when I access port 3000.

Metric for that panel:

```
topk(1, grafana_info or grafana_build_info)
```

For this metric, the query result is:

Object

```
request:Object
url:“api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query?query=topk(1%2C%20grafana_info%20or%20grafana_build_info)&time=1606318294”
method:“GET”
hideFromInspector:false
response:Object
status:“success”
data:Object
resultType:“vector”
result:Array[0]
```

Someone can help me to fix it? Do I forget to config something? Should I set different data source to this dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to edit grafana.ini file as described at [manual](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/metrics/#internal-grafana-metrics)